# How to handle 2 similar unordered dropdown lists which has same class in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

First dropdownlist HTML Code:

```html
<div id="boundlist-1018" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default x-boundlist-above" tabindex="-1" style="left: 655px; top: 356px; height: auto; width: 295px; z-index: 19001;">
<div id="boundlist-1018-outerEl" class="x-boundlist-outer-ct" style="overflow:auto">
   <div id="boundlist-1018-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
      <ul>
         <li class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected x-boundlist-item-over" role="option">aa</li>
         <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">eGDP132</li>
         <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">oracle</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Second dropdownlist HTML Code:

```html
<div id="boundlist-1012-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct" style="overflow: auto; height: 88px;">
       <ul>
          <li class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" role="option">eGDP132</li>
          <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Buddy_agt</li>
          <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">New_agt</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Frist Dropdown list code:

```
List<WebElement>internal_agt=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//[@class='xboundlist-item']"));
for (WebElement ele : internal_agt)    
{    
   String str = ele.getText();    
   System.out.println("Dropdown values are***************" +str);    
}
```

Comment: please explain in details and add the code for first dropdown

Comment: I have added the code.Through that code, Im getting only one value that too from second dropdown list

Comment: The HTML you provided is invalid. First dropdown options are within `div/div/ul/li` where as the second dropdown options are within `div/ul/li`

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using the IDs? They are different for the two lists.

Comment: Actually, I"m reading the both dropdown values are from excel sheet, so only if I take List web element, it would be possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
List<WebElement>internal_agt=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. above ur answer is working but receiving the values of second drop down list, not the value for first dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

To get first dropdown value use the x-path `(//*[@class='x-boundlist-list-ct'])[1]/ul/li`

```
List<WebElement>internal_agt=driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@class='x-boundlist-list-ct'])[1]/ul/li"));
for (WebElement ele : internal_agt)    
{    
   String str = ele.getText();    
   System.out.println("Dropdown values are***************" +str);    
}
```

For second list use the x-path `(//*[@class='x-boundlist-list-ct'])[2]/ul/li`

```
 List<WebElement>internal_agt=driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@class='x-boundlist-list-ct'])[2]/ul/li"));
   for (WebElement ele : internal_agt)    
   {    
     String str = ele.getText();    
     System.out.println("Dropdown values are***************" +str);    
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. the above 2 xpaths are matching with UI, but when I execute the code, for first xpath str value showing as oly one value (i.e) eGDP132 and for second xpath str value showing as aa

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebElement[] options1 = driver.findElements(By.Xpath(".//div[@id='boundlist-1018-listEl']/ul/li")).ToArray();
IWebElement[] options2 = driver.findElements(By.Xpath(".//div[@id='boundlist-1012-listEl']/ul/li")).ToArray();

foreach(IWebElement q in options1)
{
    System.out.println(q.Text);
}

foreach(IWebElement q in options2)
{
    System.out.println(q.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Working fine

Answer (score 0):

List options1 = 
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#boundlist-1018-listEl .xboundlist-item"));

List options2 = 
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#boundlist-1012-listEl .xboundlist-item"));

these should work

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a similar situation. Below code worked for DropDown like magic. Hope this helps.

```
public void selectValueFromDropDown(By Selector, String value) { //You can change "By Selector" to "WebElement element"
    List<WebElement> DropDownlist = driver.findElements(Selector);  
    System.out.println(DropDownlist.size());
    Assert.assertEquals(DropDownlist.size(), 12, "Provinces List does not match: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < DropDownlist.size(); i++) {         
        String strText = DropDownlist.get(i).getText();
        if(strText.contentEquals(value)) {
            DropDownlist.get(i).click();
            break; //Comment this statement to print all values from DropDown on list 
        }
        System.out.println("Province " + i + "==========> " + strText);
    }   
}
```